# Convert object to System.Type in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I need to cast an object to a `System.Type` object.

I've read that C# is statically typed so that would not be possible.

Is this true?

If yes, how can I accomplish this?

```
Assembly myDll = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllData.Path);
Type manyAttribute = myDll.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(...);
Type multiplicityAttribute = myDll.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(..);

//Here is the problem
propertiesOnOtherFile = propertiesOnOtherFile.Where(t =>
    t.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(ca => 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((multiplicityAttribute)ca).PropertyName)));
```

This is the line:

```
((multiplicityAttribute)ca).PropertyName)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT:

Due to many questions, this is my scope:

```
public class PocoClass
{
    [ManyAttribute]
    public ObjectX MyProp;
}

ManyAttribute declaration
{
    public string PropertyName;
}
```

ManyAttribute is in the dynamicly loaded DLL.
Then, as in my example above, I need to cast the customAttribute (ManyAttribute) to ManyAttribute so I check PropertyName's value.

Comment: I hope by "convert" you mean "cast"?

Comment: You can't statically cast an object to a type represented by `System.Type`.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to do?  I'm assuming reflection is your goal, but what are you attempting to do?  Just simply get a value out of a dynamic object?

Comment: @DanielA.White as I said in my question, I read about that. I was wondering if there was a different way to accomplish what I need.

Comment: @JTorres I load a Type from a DLL. Then I need to cast an object to that Type inside my linq query. Better?

Comment: And do what with it?  If you're using .net 4.0, you can just declare your object as dynamic and use properties directly.  If you need to interrogate to know what to do, you can use standard reflection. I can provide an example of either method should you require one.

Comment: @JTorres The type is not referenced in my project, hence the dynamic load. I take that type from the DLL, and check if a file has that property type and then I need to cast so I can check for a property OF that given type. Better or worse now? :D

Comment: "check if a file has that property type"...? What is a file in this case? And what do you mean by "has that property type"?

Comment: @RexM It's a C# POCO File with decorators

Comment: Do you actually need to cast to the dynamic type, or is there a base class / interface loaded in the runtime that you could cast to?  If you have some base interface, you can get static typing and reference any type members you need.

Comment: @ScottWegner yes, I need. In order to check if a property of that type has a value. I'm gonna update my question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't get this... but this should work.

```
        IEnumerable<Type> propertiesOnOtherFile = new List<Type>(); //from somewhere?

        //Here is the problem
        propertiesOnOtherFile = propertiesOnOtherFile.Where(t =>
            t.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any<dynamic>(ca => 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ca.PropertyName)));
```

Comment: It looks like you did get it :D. propertiesOnOtherFile are all properties on file PocoClass on my example. Be right back with the result. Thanks.

Comment: It did work. With the dynamic keyword C# didn't complain and allowed me to check for the value. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to access properties/methods of something without knowing its type at compile time. You're certainly in this situation:

- **reflection** – gets fairly cumbersome very quickly, even for basic things, but allows you to do pretty much anything you want.
- **dynamic** – makes C# behave similarly to dynamically typed languages, but does not allow you to do things like accessing a property whose name is also dynamic.

Since in your case the property names are also dynamic, I would say that the answer is **no**, there is no better way to manipulate objects and properties when they aren't known at compile time.

You would do well to design your architecture in such a way as to avoid accessing objects in quite such a dynamic way, but there is too little context to recommend a specific approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do doesn't make sense.

- This line: `Type multiplicityAttribute = myDll.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(..);` gets a Type that you're attempting to bind to, dynamically.
- Then you're trying to cast against it: `(multiplicityAttribute)ca)`

What are you going to do once you have it cast?

Are you:

- Attempting to get names of properties?
- Attempting to get a list of object types that have some property?
- Attempting to get the value of some static property?
- Attempting to get the value of some instance property, but you don't know the name of the class that is defining the instance?

What it seems like you're trying to do is create a generalizable approach to inspecting for something that in reality is pretty specific.  When working with Reflection, it's commonly easier to go the other direction: solve the specific case first, and then refactor to more generalizable approaches.

Comment: Check my added example, there I explain what I'm doing.